# What does tstbklt() from the Tumblr bookmarklet javascript do?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, tumblr

```
javascript: var d = document,
    w = window,
    e = w.getSelection,
    k = d.getSelection,
    x = d.selection,
    s = (e ? e() : (k) ? k() : (x ? x.createRange().text : 0)),
    f = 'http://www.tumblr.com/share',
    l = d.location,
    e = encodeURIComponent,
    p = '?v=3&u=' + e(l.href) + '&t=' + e(d.title) + '&s=' + e(s),
    u = f + p;
try {
    if (!/^(.*\.)?tumblr[^.]*$/.test(l.host)) throw (0);
    tstbklt();
} catch (z) {
    a = function () {
        if (!w.open(u, 't', 'toolbar=0,resizable=0,status=1,width=450,height=430')) l.href = u;
    };
    if (/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent)) setTimeout(a, 0);
    else a();
}
void(0)
```

Here's the code from the Tumblr's bookmarklet.
I understand it all but I can't find out what the `tstbklt();` function is for...

I'm just curious, anyone got an idea on that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `tstbklt` appears to only be defined on http://tumblr.com/goodies (account required), as follows:

```
function tstbklt() {
    alert('You\'ve successfully installed the bookmarklet!');
    return false;
}
```

On any page other than where a tstbklt function is defined, an error will be thrown and the `catch` clause will execute.

Comment: What is really weird is that I found this function in the bit.ly bookmarklet (see http://bit.ly/pages/tools). And by comparing it with the tumblr's one, it appears they are nearly identical. I suspect somebody at bit.ly has just copied/pasted then adapted the tumblr code without understanding it...